Filtering with Attributes - how to display all non-queried products below query
I added attributes to filter out products, based on their selection. For instance, I have field named 'tiled' as yes or no. If someone ticks 'yes', all the products with the attribute of 'yes' are shown. All the products with the attribute "no", are not displayed.
How can I display all the products that are not filtered BELOW the filtered query (ie: showing all the products with 'No' below the product filter)?
Inside my functions.php file, I believe this is how the filtered products are queried:
function sort_products_by_positive_attributes($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_woocommerce()) {
        // First, you would need to get all products along with their positive attributes count
        $products_with_scores = [];
         if (!empty($query->posts)) {
        foreach ($query->posts as $post) {
            $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);
            $score = get_product_positive_attributes_count($product);
            $products_with_scores[$post->ID] = $score;
        }
        }else {

        }
        // Then you would sort products by their score
        uasort($products_with_scores, function($a, $b) {
            return $b - $a;
        });

        // After sorting, modify the query to order by the IDs in the sorted order
        $sorted_ids = array_keys($products_with_scores);
        $query->set('orderby', 'post__in');
        $query->set('post__in', $sorted_ids);

        /*  
          Query that displays non-filtered products goes here

          EDIT: Possible to make an inverted $sorted_ids?     
          Do second $query here with opposite $sorted_ids?
        */

    }
}
//add_action('pre_get_posts', 'sort_products_by_positive_attributes');

function get_product_positive_attributes_count($product) {
    // You would implement the logic here to count the number of positive attributes
    $score = 0;
    // for each attribute, if it's positive, increment $score
    return $score;
}


My question seems to be downvoted. May I ask what I did? Was my question not clear or hard to understand?

"I believe this is how the filtered products are queried" - that appears to sort products by some logic (by some "score", the actual calculation of which you do not even appear to have implemented in the first place?), but I can't see the filtering you mentioned happening anywhere in there.
